# RegExpression Repeat a Word

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex that will simply repeat a string n times. For example:

```
xyz becomes xyzxyzxyz
```

I need to repeat a word n number of times (n would be a variable i pass to tell the function how many times to repeat). Note that my software limits the number of loops i can execute and that is why i am not using a simple loop.

Comment: This isn't really a use case for regex.

Comment: could you recommend another option opposed to loops?

Comment: Whats wrong with loops? function f(s, n){ if (n <= 0) return s; return s + f(s, n - 1);}

Answer (score 0):

A bash solution:

```
printf 'xyz%.0s' {1..5}
```